# How to unlock a cluster in a Packet Tracer activity?

Tags: networking

In preparation for my upcoming Cisco exam I'm reviewing all the packet tracer activities.

I am currently stuck at 3.3.2.7 Configuring PAP and CHAP. In this I am required to click on a cluster and change the encapsulation to CHAP.

Now the problem at hand is: Upon clicking on the cluster I get the warning message "Enter Cluster is locked". Since I can't enter the cluster, I can not achange encapsulation to CHAP an therefor cannot successfully complete the task.

Is there a way to unlock a cluster in Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

The original version of the .pka file had the cluster locked, when it should not have been. I had the same issue. I re-downloaded the file from the cisco netacad site and the new version lets you enter the cluster.